# How to read packet by packet from linux tun/tap

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

I have connected to an existing Tap device using

```
fd = open(...)
```

Now i want to read from it packet by packet.
if i use

```
read(fd,buffer,sizeof(buffer));
```

I wont read exactly 1 packet.

How can i read exactly 1 packet?
Is there some kind of header that says the packet length or in the worst case i will have to parse the packet and figure the length myself?

Comment: By "packet" do you mean "Ethernet frame"? A normal user doesn't have access to the protocol metadata, so if you're consuming Ethernet, you don't see the frame data, just the payload. You need elevated privileges, like libpcap does, to access the raw data.

Comment: yes i need to read the whole frame with all headers,
anyway if i just read the payload, how do i know its size so that i know how much to read? is there a header before each payload?

Comment: The "read" call will block when there's no more data, or set error `EAGAIN` in non-blocking mode.

Comment: yes but it can read much more then one frame at once, so how do i read exactly 1 frame?

Comment: @yonigo did you ever find an answer for this? If you did could you post the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I was wrong about the way `read()` reads bytes from a tap device.
It turns out when I use `read()` it reads exactly 1 frame, (or n bytes if n is smaller then frame size)

Comment: Me too, the exact experience. but I prefer to take care of any remaining or extra bytes, because this is network stream. I cannot find any manual and evidence which proves the Linux reads packets one-by-one from the tun/tap devices.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I parse packets from a raw layer3 network stream.

```
#include "bigendian.h"

#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


int pb_packet_read(PacketBuffer *b, int fd, int count, PacketCallback cb) {
    int i = 0;
    int result;
    Packet *p;
    unsigned char *start;
    size_t remaining;

    while (i < count) {
        if (b->packet == NULL) {
            if (b->level < 20 ) {
                // Read up to MTU bytes to determine packet header.
                result = read(fd, b->blob + b->level, MTU - b->level);
                if (result <= 0) {
                    return i;
                }
                b->level += result;
            }

            if (b->level < 20 ) {
                return i;
            }

            // Now, can read the packet total length
            start = b->blob;
            p = (Packet*) malloc(sizeof(Packet));
            p->start = start;
            p->version = start[0] >> 4;
            p->total_length = bigendian_deserialize_uint16(start + 2);
            memcpy(&(p->src.s_addr), start + 12, 4);
            memcpy(&(p->dst.s_addr), start + 16, 4);

            b->packet = p;


        }
        else {
            L_DEBUG("Using prev stored complete packet.");
            p = b->packet;
        }

        // Read the rest of the packet
        if (p->total_length > b->level) {
            remaining = p->total_length - b->level;
            L_DEBUG("Packet not completed, trying read more.");
            result = read(fd, b->blob + b->level, remaining);

            if(result <= 0) {
                if (result == EAGAIN) {
                    L_DEBUG("EAGAIN");
                }
                perror("READ BODY");
                return i;
            }
            b->level += result;
            if (result < remaining) {
                L_DEBUG("Not enough data");
                return i;
            }
        }

        if (b->level > p->total_length) {
            remaining = b->level - p->total_length;
            memcpy(b->blob, b->blob + p->total_length, remaining);
            b->level = remaining;
            L_DEBUG("Remaining data: %lu", remaining);
        }

        // Packet is ready to pass to callback.
        if(cb) {
            cb(p);
        }

        // Cleanup for the next packet
        i++;
        b->level = 0;
        free(b->packet);
        b->packet = NULL;
    }
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Libpcap:
http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap3_man.html

You can read packets coming in through whatever interface you specify, in this example its wlan1.

```
int main(){
    char *device = NULL;
    pcap_t* descr;

     if(argc > 0)
       device = "wlan1";

    if(device == NULL)
    {
      printf("%s\n",errbuf);
      exit(1);
    }
    descr = pcap_open_live(device,BUFSIZ,0,-1,errbuf);

    if(descr == NULL){ printf("pcap_open_live(): %s\n",errbuf); exit(1); }

    errbuf[0] = 0;
    handle = pcap_open_live(device, BUFSIZ,1,0,errbuf);

    pcap_loop(handle,-1, process_packet, NULL);
    pcap_close(handle);
    return 0;
  }
```

Where in `pcap_loop` the process_packet is the callback of the packets coming in.

Let me know if there is anything you are unsure of.

---

P.S. Here is some links that should help you with parsing 802.11/ethernet headers.

http://madwifi-project.org/wiki/DevDocs/RadiotapHeader
http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section2.html
http://www.cacetech.com/documents/PPI%20Header%20format%201.0.7.pdf

Comment: thanks!
but it seems i was wrong, when i read() from a tap device i get exactly 1 frame (or less if bytes_to_read is less).
so i didnt realy have to do anything just use read and it gives my a frame..